# Beginner trying Python Turtle module

Tags: python

I'm a beginner just trying to mess around with Python. I wrote some very simple code using the Turtle module, but something I can't figure out is why the GUI closes immediately after it's done drawing?

I've tried turtle.getscreen()._root.mainloop(), and the sleep command (which my cmd doesn't recognize), but to no avail. Any thoughts?

Realize this is a trivial question, but people say the best way to understand things is to get in there and do random things :)

Code ( extracted from comment):

```
from turtle import *
setup()
title("turtle test")
clear()
down()
forward(50)
right(90)
forward(50)
right(90)
forward(50)
right(90)
forward(500)
turtle.getscreen()._root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes. Post your code. :) If you don't show us what you're doing, we can't possibly tell you what you're doing wrong. "I'm doing something, and it's not working like I'd expect. How do I fix it?" - do you have an answer based on that info? Please edit your post and provide some detail that might allow someone to see what you're doing wrong (or not doing that you should be). Thanks. :)

Comment: from turtle import *
setup()
title("turtle test")
clear()

down()
forward(50)
right(90)
forward(50)
right(90)
forward(50)
right(90)
forward(500)

turtle.getscreen()._root.mainloop()

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. It's hard to format and read in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'turtle' is not defined
```

Because you did `from turtle import *` you do not have a `turtle` module for `turtle.getscreen()._root.mainloop()`, generating the error above.

Instead, try `mainloop()`.

Answer (score 1):

The screen should not "disappear"- if you are calling the mainloop() method correctly - 
however, if there is a syntax error in your source code, or other Python exception is raised, the program would finish immediately.

If instead of clicking on your program, you run  it from a command terminal, you will see the error traceback.

POst it on your question (along with your code, properly formated, which you can do by clicking on "edit" on the question), so that people may help you further.

(btw, calling the mainloop method in the way you describe is works for me).

Now one thing: the built-in Python Tkinter turtle is mostly a toy, and the fun part is playing along with it in the interactive mode, typing commands to it as you go, not to write a script with it.  If you want to do some serious art using a turtle model for driving, you be better writing your own turtle.

Comment: +1: but the last paragraph is off-base. Here's at least [7 ways you could use turtle](http://python-turtle-demo.googlecode.com/files/SevenWaysToUseTurtle-PyCon2009.pdf). See http://code.google.com/p/python-turtle-demo/

Comment: Ahh..it has been rewriten in Python 2.6, and can be used for general purpose things now. Thanks @J.F.Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Fix it like this

`from turtle import *`

`setup()`

`title("turtle test")`

`clear()`

`down()`

`forward(50)`

`right(90)`

`forward(50)`

`right(90)`

`forward(50)`

`right(90)`

`forward(500)`

`done()`

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be to remove root because it's not assigned ,here is my code try it out:

```
from turtle import *
setup()
title("turtle test")
clear()
down()
forward(50)
right(90)
forward(50)
right(90)
forward(50)
right(90)
forward(500)
mainloop()
```

Okay this is maybe too much but you can use a for loop(a loop that repeats for some amount of time):

```
from turtle import *
setup()
title("turtle test")
clear()
down()
for i in range(3):
    forward(50)
    right(90)
forward(500)
mainloop()
```

Python is a great language consider working on learning it!